# android app load and resize images

Tags: android, android-webview

I need load image from assets 
I can read text file
but i can not read images and get to BitmapFactory
my simple code

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resources.getAssets().open("Untitled-1.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images should be placed in the `/res/drawable-XXX`-folders ([see this table](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ResourceTypes)).

If you put them in the `/res/drawable-XX`-folder, you can load them (with Java) using something like this to show it in a `ImageView`:

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.drawme);
view.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
```

If you need it as a `Bitmap`-Object, you can use the [decodeResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int%29)-method `BitmapFactory`-class:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: great , so i have file name (smiler 'Untitled-1.jpg'), i have not image id (smiler R.drawable.icon)   , i call java function on JavaScript and give her file name tnx